# read local file content in bazel build system

Tags: bazel

Hi I would like to read a content of local file in .bzl file.

```
    print(onefile.basename)
    #content = ctx.read
    #content=ctx.file.onefile
    #print(onefile.content)
```

Answer (score 4):

`.bzl` code cannot read files, and can't make decisions based on contents of files.

You must create actions (e.g. `ctx.actions.run`), make the file an action input, and have the action read the file.

`.bzl` code can load other `.bzl` files though, you might find that useful.

Comment: Can you at least have an action read the file and extract a value from it which can later be used within bazel?

Comment: No. The BUILD and .bzl  files must fully describe the build. What is your specific use case?

Comment: My use case was to configure build rules based on information stored in a different file.

Comment: So... we have to generate a `.bzl` file, and then read it???

Comment: Yes, but you need to do it in an external repository rule. You can't have a normal build rule (e.g. `genrule`) create a `.bzl` file that another package in the same repo loads.